# Margin collapse on inline-block elements?

Tags: css

Margins of blocks elements collapse, but not inline-blocks.
Is there a way to force inline-blocks margins to collapse?

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper .el {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper.block .el { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper block">
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
    <div class="el"></div>
</div>
```

Anyone have an idea?
I have already read the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is documented in the spec that margins of inline-block elements do not collapse:

> **[8.3.1 Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)**
>
> - Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).
> - Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do
>     not collapse with their in-flow children.
> - Margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).
> - **Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).**
> - ...

Therefore **the answer is No**. You probably need to alter the margins of the element.

Comment: For instance, by a negative `margin-bottom` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/0bzm5gf3/5/

Comment: +1 for answering with a credible source that confirm the 'No' answer.

Comment: `margin-collapse: collapse;` one day, one day.

Comment: @TarranJones - maybe by 2040 they will get to it. hopefully `margin-collapse` property will happen before they manage to invent human-level AI. it's a tight race.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no" because that's not how inline boxes work so it can't be forced as you asked for. Anything else would be just manipulating the margins of elements which is only a trick or hack.

Answer (score -3):

If I get you right you want to remove that extra margin that `inline-block` elements have assign `font-size: 0;` to the parent element of the corresponding div.

Check this post:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Try assigning `font-size: 0;` just to the class `.wrapper`.

Comment: Then I think I'm not getting your question. Exactly which of those margins you want to remove?

Comment: If you look at the example in the question, you'll notice there is 2 wrapper containers. Both contain elements with the *same* margin even though both doesn't render the same. The only difference is that the first one elements are display: block; and the second one are display: inline-block;

Comment: Got it. I think that's not possible, take a look at this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html. The box model just doesn't work like that. I would try to target those specific margins and tweak them. Good luck!

Comment: @mencina might want to consider revising / removing your answer - looks like you were thinking about the 1px margin

Comment: The example has two issues and @mencina solved one of them. The problem is, they didn't ask to solve that issue.
[#5078239](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)