# Why do vertical margins not collapse?

Tags: html, css, margin

Consider the following MWE

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
  div.compact-inverse {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  div.compact-inverse > input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 12px 0;
  }
  
  div.compact-inverse > label {
    display: inline;
    margin: 12px 0;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: pink;
  }
  
  div.compact-inverse > p {
    display: block;
    margin: 12px 0;
    padding-left: 34px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: cyan;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <form>
    <div class='compact-inverse'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='delete_imported' /><label>Delete originals</label>
      <p>Original files will be deleted after the import when possible.</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the screenshot, the vertical margin between the first row (`input` with `label`) and the second row (`p`) is not collapsed but stacked.

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> Adjoining vertical margins collapse

and

> Two margins are adjoining if and only if … both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context

The `label` and `input` are inline elements. They don't generate block-level boxes.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455932/margin-collapse-on-inline-block-elements